# how can i use scanners string input in if()

Tags: if-statement, java.util.scanner

i want user to type a number and choose the operator and then type another number and learn the result of it. i tried to code it but i failed im asking for reason for error and maybe possible solution

my code is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
        System.out.println("Type your first number:");
        double first_num = scan.nextDouble();
    
        System.out.println("Choose the operator"+
        "you want: +, -, x, /");
        String operator = scan.nextLine();
    
        System.out.println("Type your second number:");
        double second_num = scan.nextDouble();
    
    
    
        if(operator="+")
        {
            double sum_result = first_num + second_num;
            System.out.println("The result is: " + 
            sum_result);
        }
    
        else if(operator="-")
        {
            double ext_result = first_num - second_num;
            System.out.println("The result is: " + 
            ext_result);
        }
    
        else if(operator="x")
        {
            double pro_result = first_num * second_num;
            System.out.println("The result is: " + 
            pro_result);
        }
    
        else if(operator="/")
        {
            double div_result = first_num / second_num;
            System.out.println("The result is: " + 
            div_result);
        }
    
    }
}
```

and i get this error

```
Test.java:22: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean
        if(operator="+")
                   ^
Test.java:29: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean
        else if(operator="-")
                        ^
Test.java:36: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean
        else if(operator="x")
                        ^
Test.java:43: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean
        else if(operator="/")
                        ^
4 errors
```

im not sure what to do in order to use scanner's input as a string in if line

Answer (score 0):

By typing `operator="+"` you are setting the variable `operator` to the value `"+"`, which is why the error says `String cannot be converted to boolean`.

If statements require a boolean value to determine whether or not the code inside should run, and `operator="+"` is just a string.

You mean to instead compare `operator` with each of the strings, by using a double equal sign: `(operator == "+")`. Do this for all of your if and else if statements.

Comment: thank you so much. im a beginner that really helped me

Comment: no problem, glad I could help! If this solved your question, be sure to approve the answer :) @yakuzaa31